# How do I mock the entity manager coming from the @Transaction() decorator

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

TypeORM provides an `@Transaction()` decorator for your functions. It will wrap the entire function in a transaction.

My understanding is that if your function looks like this

```
@Transaction()
public myFunction(
  myParam: string,
  @TransactionManager() entityManager?: EntityManager
){
  //do some stuff with entityManager
}
```

then when you call the function without providing an entity manager of your own typeORM will inject an `EntityManager` instance into your function.

I'm running into an issue where I create an entity manager mock in my unit test and pass it in to the function. I'm thinking it will prevent typeORM from injecting it's own. However, I get a `ConnectionNotFound` error. This tells me that TypeORM is still injecting it's own entity manager. How can I force it to use the entity manager that I pass in to the function?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to `@Transaction()` (see it's code [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/749511d981f6b9a1a08113b23e8779a91cda78f8/src/decorator/transaction/Transaction.ts)). You could fix this by mocking it like:

```js
jest.mock('typeorm/decorator/transaction/Transaction', () => ({
  Transaction() {
    return jest.fn();
  },
}));
```

now the real `@Transaction()` won't be called anymore

not sure if this is the best way tho.